# numpy `np.array()[None]` behavior

Tags: numpy

```
import numpy as np  # specify import if you are using it with some other name

np.array([1, 2, 3]) -> array([1, 2, 3])

np.array([1, 2, 3])[None] -> array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Notice the second lines has one additional dimension. Can someone explain this behavior to me? It's not multiplication. `np.array([1, 2, 3])*[None]` will raise an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the same thing as `np.array([1, 2, 3])[np.newaxis]`.  `None` simply happens to be the value chosen for `newaxis`; it could have been anything that isn't otherwise a meaningful slice or index value.

Comment: I would normally use `np.array([1,2,3])[None, :]`, making it clear that I am adding a new dimension at the start.  `numpy` adds the trailing `:` automatically.  But often in broadcasting this `None` isn't needed - it's added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> numpy.array([1,2,3])[0]  # find values at specific index in array
1
>>> numpy.array([1,2,3])[1]
2
>>> numpy.array([1,2,3])[None] # when you pass None as index it gives you whole list
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

To your confusion when you are using `numpy.array(<your-list>)*[value]` this will multiply all the values in array with value. Here all values in your list is integer which can only be multiply with integer or float values.
`None` is a `NoneType object` in python (to be precise it's my statement for python3 not much aware on this for python2) and you can not multiply integer values with None object. because if you process `2 * None` it doesn't make any sense.